# 擬似的な個人情報を生成できるOSSのライブラリ/ツールを教えてください

Tags: テスト

テストで使用するため、擬似個人情報を生成できるツールを探しています。
生成したい情報は日本/日本語の氏名・郵便番号・住所などです。

Webサービスであれば[疑似個人情報データ生成サービス](http://hogehoge.tk/personal/)などがあるのですが、
自分でカスタマイズ・メンテナンスを行いながら運用していきたいため、OSSのものを探しています。

言語などについてはは特にこだわりはありません。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

python の faker なら日本語の氏名・郵便番号・住所を生成できそうですがいかがでしょうか
http://qiita.com/ohbarye/items/452fefa2be5d56268b50
自分では試していないのであしからずお願いします

Comment: 住所と郵便番号の整合性については考慮されていないようですが、それ以外はまさに探していたものでした！